# PostgreSQL query returning empty

Tags: sql, postgresql

Can any one tell me why my query is returning empty. I am pretty new to postgreSQL and I'm not sure if I'm accessing the two arrays correctly. I also tried a subquery with status.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT * FROM piecedef pd, pieceinst pi 
WHERE pi.truckno IN ('29,26,25,2,16,15,14,13,12,11,10')
AND pi.status IN (3601,102,201)        
AND pi.defid=pd.pdid
AND pd.projectid='4592'
ORDER BY pi.piid
```

truckno is a varchar (15) and status is int4 (32). Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT * FROM piecedef pd, pieceinst pi
WHERE pi.truckno IN ('29','26','25','2','16','15','14','13','12','11','10') 
AND pi.status IN (3601,102,201)        
AND pi.defid=pd.pdid
AND pd.projectid='4592'
ORDER BY pi.piid
```

What your error seems to be: an array of varchar needs each element between quotes, otherwise it will be considered as on eelement of a long varchar...

Comment: Nicely done working that out without any table data, schema, etc.